Axios create Instance doesn't seem to return error
I created an axios instance class like this using singleton pattern
import Axios, { AxiosInstance, AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from "axios";

class httpApiService {
  public server: AxiosInstance;
  public client: AxiosInstance;
  private static instance: httpApiService;

  constructor() {
    this.server = this.createAxiosInstance(process.env.BACKEND_URL);
    this.client = this.createAxiosInstance(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL);

    this.initializeInterceptors(this.client);
    this.initializeInterceptors(this.server);
  }

  public static getInstance(): httpApiService {
    if (!httpApiService.instance) {
      httpApiService.instance = new httpApiService();
    }
    return httpApiService.instance;
  }

  private createAxiosInstance(baseURL: string | undefined): AxiosInstance {
    const configuration = {
      baseURL,
      headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      withXSRFToken: true,
    };
    if (typeof baseURL === "undefined") {
      delete configuration.baseURL;
    }
    let instance = Axios.create(configuration);
    return instance;
  }

  private initializeInterceptors(instance: AxiosInstance): void {
    instance.interceptors.response.use(
      (response: AxiosResponse) => {
        return response;
      },
      (error: AxiosError) => {
        if (error.response?.status === 422) {
          console.error("Validation error: ", error.response.data);
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  }
}

const httpApi = httpApiService.getInstance();

export default httpApi;

Then I am using this in my react component
Page.tsx
import httpApi from "@/utils/httpApi";
const saveAdmin = async (formData: saveAdminData) => {
  try {
    const response = await httpApi.client.post("/api-admin/admin", formData);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
};
const Page = () => {
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<adminData> = async (
    data: adminData
  ): Promise<void> => {
    let formData: saveAdminData = {
      role_id: data.roles,
      username: data.username,
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
      password_confirmation: data.password_confirm,
    };
    const response = await saveAdmin(formData);
    console.log(response); //SHOWING UNDEFINED
  };
  return (<div> Remaining code ....</div>)
}

I am not sure why the interceptor is not working to return the error when it is called with axios.createInstance. However, when we call it normally using axios.post() , the saveAdmin manages to catch the error.
